# Ajax - JSON - Beginner

Tags: json, ajax

The code below "has been" successfully returning the users.json file in an html table. I modified the json, but the code continues to return the original json. I delete the file, then add it back and then it can't find the file. I have cleared what I thought was the browser cache, to no avail.

Question #1: Where does the server "look" for the users.json file on my web server?
Question #2: How can I assure I'm getting the latest changes, when the user clicks the button?

```js
 <script>
        function CreateTableFromJSON() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "get",
                url: ***"users.json",***
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (jsonData) {
                    var table = $('table');
                    table.empty();
                    var name = document.getElementById('name').value.toUpperCase();
                    $.each(jsonData, function (key, item) {
                        var table_row = $('<tr>');
                        $.each(item, function (itemKey, itemValue) {
                            if (key == 0) {
                                table.append($('<th>', { html: itemKey }));
                            }
                            if (item.LastName.startsWith(name)) {
                                table_row.append($('<td>', { html: itemValue }));
                            }
                        });

                        table.append(table_row);
                    }
                    );

                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("json not found");
                }
            });
        }

    </script>
```

```css
 <style>
        th, td, p, input {
            font: 14px Verdana;
        }

        table, th, td {
            border: solid 1px #DDD;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            padding: 2px 3px;
            text-align: left;
        }

        th {
            font-weight: bold;
        }
    </style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>

    <div>
        <input type="button" onclick="CreateTableFromJSON()" value="Create Table From JSON" />
        <input type='text' id='name' placeholder='Search Initial ' />

    </div>
    <p id="showData"></p>
    <table id="tbl"></table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hit url into broser and check you are getting response in return. second add nocache header in ajax request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by your first question.  It will "look" at whatever location is in your url.

For your second question: you want to turn off browser caching.  Add "cache: false", eg

```
            type: "get",
            url: ***"users.json",***
            dataType: "json",
            cache: false
```

Comment: Is that the root or the www folder or somewhere else? I originally did not have the mime type set properly and in my haste, put the file in several locations. Again , I’m a beginner.

Comment: @PaulCr125 again, not sure I understand the question. For example, if you had a static file named users.json on your web server, and you simply wanted to serve that up to the browser,  a url like https://yourdomain.com/users.json will return that json file to your browser, and it will display.  But you obviously are doing something different.  You need a server-side method in your web application that fetches a json file (from any location you want) and returns it to the ajax call.  In order to answer that question you would need to provide a lot more information about the web server and etc.

Comment: @PaulCr125 or, if you simply want to return a static json file from the disk to that ajax call, you can put it in the root folder of your web application, and access it with a url such as https://yourdomain.com/users.json.  If you put it in a sub-folder (eg Users), then the url would be https://yourdomain.com/Users/users.json

Comment: Appreciate the comments . The cache:false did the trick. Moved the file to my data directory and access it with url:/data/users.json. Also this will only be an intranet app, never internet.

Comment: @PaulCr125, if you are happy with the answer then please click the check mark so that other users of the site know the question is answered.

Comment: Not sure what check mark to click I'm satisfied with the answer.

Comment: @PaulCr125 at the top of my answer on the left you should see the number 0, and underneath that a large checkmark.  Click the checkmark and it will turn green, indicating "answered".  That way other users of the site know the questions is answered and they won't waste time clicking on it.